# Custom Validation for Checkbox in MVC5 razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I am trying to force a required terms and conditions checkbox for a view.  I followed the code sample outlined on this forum: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/8UFa191212-Custom-Validation-for-Checkbox-in-MVC-Razor.html but if I set a breakpoint within the IsValid method, is it never reached.  Also, the ModelState.IsValid returns true when it should be false; if the checkbox is never selected.

Here is the code for the ViewModel:

```
public class TermsConditionViewModel
{
    [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "The terms and conditions must be read and agreed to complete the registration process.")]
    [Display(Name = "")]
    public bool TermsConditionsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code for the custom data annotations:

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value is bool && (bool)value;
    }
    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "checkbox", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }


}

public class MustBeSelected : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable // IClientValidatable for client side Validation
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || (int)value == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule { ValidationType = "dropdown", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }
}
```

Here is the javascript code for the client side validation

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("dropdown", function (options) {
//  debugger;
if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "SELECT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "SELECT-ONE") {
    options.rules["required"] = true;
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages["required"] = options.message;
    }
}
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("checkbox", function (options) {
if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") {
    options.rules["required"] = true;
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages["required"] = options.message;
    }
}
});
```

Here is the markup that is generated

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-checkbox="The terms and conditions must be read and agreed to complete the registration process." data-val-required="The  field is required." id="TermsConditionsCompleted" name="TermsConditionsCompleted" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="TermsConditionsCompleted" type="hidden" value="false" />&nbsp;I have read and agree with the terms and conditions described above
```

Are there any extra configurations that need to take place for this to work?  All of the examples I found so far seem to be setup the same way, no configurations in Web.Config, Global.asax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some of the jQuery validation steps.
I've solved the same issue and accomplished the same task following the path made at this link:
http://www.yogihosting.com/client-side-validation-asp-net-mvc/

Hope it helps you.

Alessandro

Comment: Don't hide answers in links that will be dead in an internet moment. Answers should be self-contained and not rely on external links.

Answer (score -2):

Your solution seems really overkill, instead I would just add a jQuery method on form submit that ensures that the checkbox is checked.

Much less code.

Comment: How would I check the validation server side in case someone disabled javascript?

Comment: check it manually and add the error into the ModelState:

If (model.Checkboxfield == false) {
   ModelState.AddError("CheckBoxField", "You must accept the privacy policy");
}